# Cookie generated after login with Azure AD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure-active-directory, access-token

Every time I login to my application using Azure AD, it generates me a Cookie ... I would like to know if this Cookie generated is my access token!

[image]

Can you help me with this? I searched in several places, but I didn't find the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to capture the cookie, and then use https://jwt.ms/ to parse it.

If you do not see the result of decoding the token, it is not your access token. Conversely, if you can correctly obtain the decoded token and verify it correctly, it means that it is your access token. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens).